# retrieve google autocomplete results to vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-search

I am trying to implement google search suggestion into my application, I have search field and I have example string like this `https://clients1.google.com/s?hl=en&client=opera&q=stack&_=1578059207899`. If you copy and paste this string into browser url you will get some search suggestion. But in Vue application I alwaus have this error
`Access to fetch at 'https://clients1.google.com/s?hl=en&client=opera&q=stack&_=1578059207899' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
I believe this is not vue.js problem, but I need to solve this inside the vue application.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: This is not a VueJS-specific problem. Basically, Google is not returning a header that allows cross-origin access to the data returned from that URL. There isn't really much you can do since it is done intentionally by Google. The reason is simple: Google wants you to use their pre-existing API.

Comment: @Terry I understand that it is not vue problem. What is pre-existing API?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot perform Google Searches via an API. The closest you can get is the Google Custom Search API, but it only returns results for sites that you have control over.

Comment: @Terry this is possible. I have this example https://www.ukr.net/ it is in russian, but you can find serach on the top and it is work. I get the example search string from this site https://clients1.google.com/s?callback=citySearch&hl=ru&client=opera&q=%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB&_=1578059207899. The string have callbcak, but this site made with jquery, so I need to implement it into vue